# How to optimize MySQL indexes/query for modular search?

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing, myisam

I have a large MyISAM table with ~200,000,000 rows of data representing events which are meant to be searchable via a web UI. The UI is a page of the "Advanced Search" variety, so the user can enter search criteria for any combination of searchable fields.

A simplified version of the table structure is something like this:

```
events
event_id, event_code, place_id, person_id, date, type

people
person_id, person_name
```

and the user is allowed to search using a required type, an optional date range, and zero or more of event_codes, place_ids, and/or person_names.

In order to optimize the table for this type of search, do I need an index on every permutation of columns, except the ones that don't include type? Or is there a more efficient way to index the table.

Currently, the table has a primary index which covers event_code, place_id, person_id, date, and type, so when you search using all fields the response is acceptable. But if you try to search using e.g. only a date range, the query essentially never returns.

Comment: To provide the most useful information, we really need to see the actual queries that will be executed especially including:
- WHERE clauses
- GROUP BY clauses
- HAVING clauses
which could affect performance a great deal.

Comment: 200M events!!! You are very successfull :-D

Answer (score 0):

MySQL uses indexes from first field to last, so if you are not using the earlier fields in an index, the index will not be used (as you observed with date).

I wouldn't necessarily say you need an index on every permutation, but at least a few. Since you've stated the type is required, I would start the indexes with that and make a relatively small initial set of two field index with each of the other searchable fields being the second field.

*Also of great importance is how you form the actual search conditions. If you are doing operations on indexed fields, like `DAYOFWEEK(date)`, no amount of indexes will help.*